# How to get a consistent bluetooth audio playback?

Tags: sound, keyboard, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I am trying to use **bluetooth audio speakers**, as my integred laptop speakers are so awful... The speaker is a Bose Soundlink mini and works just fine with my smartphone for example.

When I try to use it with my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04), it works ok, until I begin to work. Then sound begins to shutter, with this kind of logs:

```
Sep  3 17:29:38 franck-ThinkPad-T430s pulseaudio[3673]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 30147 us (= 5316 bytes) in audio stream
Sep  3 17:29:38 franck-ThinkPad-T430s pulseaudio[3673]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 79152 us (= 13960 bytes) in audio stream
Sep  3 17:29:41 franck-ThinkPad-T430s pulseaudio[3673]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 3467134 us (= 611600 bytes) in audio stream
```

This happens as soon as I ***type on the keyboard*** (be it in libreoffice or in a terminal, or whatever). The keyboard is not a bluetooth keyboard, in case you ask.

When using internal speakers, I don't suffer the same problem.

So, is there a trick to give the full bluetooth audio stack higher priority and get a consistent audio plackback ? (bluetoothd ? pulseaudio ? low level interupts ? ???)

**UPDATE**:
my bluetooth controller is attached to (internal) USB.

```
$ lsusb -v -s 001:004

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem I had.
This helped me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/624833/atheros-ar3011-bluetooth-disconnects-when-wireless-lan-is-heavily-loaded
//Stefan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found a solution (in fact several one):

1. Add threadirqs to my kernel params
2. was better, but this was not enough, I also had to install rtirq-init (you should check if you kernel supports this, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55001/61603)

I then had an (almost) perfect bt sound playback.

Another option seems to use linux-lowlatency kernel. I still have to test this, but it should work. What is unclear is the drackbacks (power consumption ?).

Comment: I had the same problem. This solution works! Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Notice that I've also been using the lowlatency kernel since, with no apparent drawback I could notice...