# Atheros AR3011 bluetooth disconnects, when wireless LAN is heavily loaded

Tags: networking, wireless, sound, bluetooth, atheros

Has anybody already had an issue with the Bluetooth Loudspeakers (Bose) that the sound is interrupted or stops sometimes.

After some testing I found out if I disable Wireless LAN the connection works fine.

If I load a website for example the sound gets interrupted.

If I do nothing besides listening to music via Bluetooth it works perfectly.

Additional information:

- Ubuntu = 14.04 LTS
- Main Board = Asus P8 Z68 V Pro
- Loudspeakers = Bose SoundLink Mobile Speakers
- Internal Bluetooth and WLAN Card

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
```

*Any suggestions or fixes?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably happens because of wireless and bluetooth interference. Wi-Fi and bluetooth share same radio frequency. With some bluetooth chips it is possible to turn on "btcoexist" parameter, which helps to avoid this problem.

Your wireless/bluetooth combo chip supports it. You can turn this option on by running

```
sudo modprobe ath9k btcoex_enable=1
```

To make this option permanent you can do this:

```
echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

This solution should work for Atheros AR3011 and AR3012 combo chips. But USB chip names are not always shown correctly in lsusb.

But if wireless chip is handled by ath9k, there is a good chance that it will work.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, but gives explanation on why this may happen and gives a direction how to try to fix it.

Comment: Yep!  That makes it a comment! (and not an answer)

Comment: wired LAN do not affect the connection, only W-LAN affectes the Connection.

Comment: @Fabby Fixed it, but still I do not agree, that first answer was too bad ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6: I agree it's an excellent answer now!  Upvoted!  :-)