# Distorted sound with bluetooth speaker in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, 16.04, speakers

I just upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 this morning.

When I got to work I connected my Blackweb Tsunami bluetooth speakers, and they connected fine, but the sound is so distorted, and almost sounds monotone.

It sounds horrible, these speakers worked perfectly in Ubuntu 15.10.

**EDIT:**

When I try to set the device sound mode from `HSP/HFP` to `A2DP` as suggested in LiveWireBTs answer the sound stops working completely.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of several others, for example this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/766554/a2dp-bluetooth-doesnt-work-on-16-04?rq=1  Here in the comments the following workaround was suggested `[..] In Sound settings change the affected device settings to HSP/HFP > disconnect Bluetooth device > connect Bluetooth device again and change to A2DP in Sound setting[..]`- by user http://askubuntu.com/users/350520/mike

Comment: Another duplicate question has an accepted answer, although with some console action required. http://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working

Comment: Sounds like the problem I had.
This helped me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/624833/atheros-ar3011-bluetooth-disconnects-when-wireless-lan-is-heavily-loaded

Answer (score 7):

Go to Sound Settings, select your Bluetooth audio device and check that the device is set to **A2DP** not HSP/HFP (which is mono and has very low quality).

[image]

**Edit:** If Bluetooth audio stops working after you do that in 16.04 you need to apply the following workaround: https://askubuntu.com/a/817926/40581

Comment: After re-reading what i posted i forgot to mention that every time i select high fidelity/A2DP the sound does not work. like if i select that setting no sound comes out of my speaker at all.