# Bluetooth speaker no sound in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, a2dp, bluez

After upgrading to Kubuntu 16.04 my JBL Flip 2 bluetooth speaker no longer works.

It connects just fine, and the sound is set to use A2DP sink with the speaker, but I get no sound.

I found some places claiming I had to change `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`, but that file no longer exists.

Does anyone know how I get it to work again?

Comment: Same issue with JBL Charge 2+ after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. Pairing is successful (the speaker beeps to confirm the connexion and Ubuntu shows the speaker as connected) but no sound is reproduced when requesting pulse to send audio to the BT device. Maybe an issue with Pulse as the vu-meter freezes when trying to send audio to the speaker and the port only contains "Speaker" when it included "Off", "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)" and "Telephony Duplex (HSP/HFP)" before.

Comment: Clues from syslog : 

/// pulseaudio[1942]: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-device.c: Default profile not connected, selecting off profile
/// bluetoothd[790]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_A6_94_EE_96_4E/fd0: fd(24) ready
/// pulseaudio[1942]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Transport TryAcquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_A6_94_EE_96_4E/fd0 (Operation Not Authorized)
/// kernel: [  842.519817] input: 0C:A6:94:EE:96:4E as /devices/virtual/input/input15

Comment: I opened a bug for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1577197

Comment: Similar from 2014: https://askubuntu.com/q/481951/396228

Comment: I just found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure -- first suggestion of killing pulseaudio, deleting some files, and restarting pulseaudio did the trick for me (Ubuntu 20.04, Sony XM3 headphones).

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 16.04.  For me, there isn't a real fix, but I can get the speaker to work. I'm running Kubuntu so these steps are for KDE, and I'm not sure what the equivalent Unity steps are, but I'd imagine they're similar.

Here's what I did:

1. Let the speaker connect.
2. In your audio settings, change the profile to "Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" or equivalent[image]
3. <s>Power off</s> Disconnect the speaker
4. <s>Restart the bluetooth service</s>

   `sudo service bluetooth restart`
5. <s>Power the speaker back on and</s> reconnect
6. In your audio settings, change the profile back to "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)" or equivalent
   [image]

A2DP should now work. So far, it seems that things only go wrong when I try to connect in A2DP mode. Until there is a real fix/workaround, I am going to try to remember to always switch to HSP/HSF mode before powering off or disconnecting the speaker.

**UPDATE:**

It's sufficient to connect, switch to HSP/HFP mode, disconnect, reconnect, and switch back to A2DP mode. There is no reason to restart the bluetooth service.

Comment: works for me..surprised though. Did you find a permanent fix?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't.  I use bluetooth audio all the time (more than my built-in audio) so I'm hoping this gets fixed soon.

Comment: Such a fuss for a simple sound to come out of a mechanical thingle!! This was to let everyones' life easier...

Comment: this is the only way I've found to correct it as well. That or repair, but that essentially does the same thing anyway.

Comment: nothing new on this ? I experience the same issue... Thanks for the fix btw ;)

Comment: this is not working for me :(

Comment: Does **not** work for me with Sony MDR-XB950BT; switching to HSP/HFP mode causes it to (uncontrollably) switch to Off mode. Disconnecting and reconnecting causes it to (uncontrollably) switch back to A2DP mode and there's still no audio.

Comment: I have a similar problem with Ubuntu 16.04 + Philips bluetooth headphones. For me the phones get automatically connected on HSP/HFP and works fine, when changing to A2DP mode the sound fallbacks to internal speakers and I can't have A2DP sound. Reconnecting the phones fix it, currently testing the fix:

"In order to auto-connect a2dp for some devices, add this to /etc/pulse/default.pa:
`load-module module-switch-on-connect`"
Described on https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp

Comment: @JaminSore: Try the script in my answer, this will do everything for u

Comment: @pylover I'll give it a shot when I get a new speaker or fix my old one ... I'd prefer running a script to manually going through these steps every time.

Comment: I don't see at all what the equivalent steps are under Unity. The Unity sound settings window doesn't mention "profiles" or anything like "A2DP sink" or "HSP/HFP". I see [this](https://i.imgur.com/VY3n37s.png).

Answer (score 12):

After testing all workarounds, i wrote a python script to change profile, disconnect, reconnect and set profile to a2dp.

run it after pair/turning-on the device with python3.5.

https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae#file-a2dp-py

**EDIT 1**

```
$ python3.5 a2dp.py 
Connection MADE
Selecting device:
Device MAC: 00:22:37:3D:DB:1A
Device ID: bluez_card.00_22_37_3D_DB_1A
Sink: bluez_sink.00_22_37_3D_DB_1A
Turning off audio profile.
Disconnecting the device.
Connecting againt.
Setting A2DP profile
Device ID: bluez_card.00_22_37_3D_DB_1A
Updating default sink
Exiting bluetoothctl
```

Comment: Your script from Gist worked beautifully!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue. For me worked to remove the bluetooth device and search for it again and reconnect.

Comment: This solved it for me . It stopped working when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.