# a2dp problems on ubuntu 16.4 unable to connect

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones, a2dp

There are a lot of topics about this but none of them helps .
when i try to change profile of my headphones to `a2dp` it gives me following error on blueman [image].

Before i was able to connect only disconnecting after initial connection and connecting back through the buttons on my headphones but it doesn't work anymore.

when i try to load bluetooth discover module using the command `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` i get `Failure: Module initialization failed` error.

At the moment i can only connect to hsp/hfp profile which results sounds from star trek

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/765233/pulseaudio-fails-to-set-card-profile-to-a2dp-sink-how-can-i-see-the-logs-and) helped me connect to A2DP but it isn't a real fix

Comment: it tells me there no such profile

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1574324 is a similar bug

Answer (score 0):

Setting line in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf to

> MultiProfile = single

helped me to switch profile on a2dp_sink.
After changing file you need to restart bluetooth service.
My system is Xubuntu 18.04.