# New bluetooth headphones only playing in mono

Tags: gnome, bluetooth, headphones, mono

My new pair of Bluetooth headphones arrived today but when I paired them to my computer they will only play in mono, with Sound settings Test Speakers only showing in mono also. Also the quality of the sound being very poor when listening to music or a youtube stream. However they are fine with my television.

I am using a mini bluetooth usb adapter and the headphones are the Bluedio T2S. I am lead to believe that any usb adapter (like mine) should work fine with these.

Anybody got any ideas, would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**
I've tried that a few times setting the profile from "HSP/HFP" to "A2DP Sink"

and it still doesn’t seem to function even if I repair the device, which I have tried numerous times.

In addition, when I setup the connection using the Bluetooth Manager app and set the Audio Profile to A2DP Sink I  get "Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink".

Comment: Toggle modes - A2DP-HSP - and try again. Toggle again if it still doesn't work in  stereo. Make sure you end up in the A2DP mode, of course.

Comment: Hey Celtic. I'm not sure what you mean; to toggle in Sound settings or on the headphones?

Comment: In sound settings.

Comment: Neither  A2DP Sink or HSP/HFP modes are making a difference.

Comment: Do you understand what those modes are, right?

Comment: Not really sure.

Comment: I figured that already. HSP (HeadSet Profile) is Mono + Microphone whereas A2DP is Stereo (no Mic). You're already using the former and you want the latter. That's why I said *Make sure you end up in the A2DP mode, of course*. So, after toggling (a couple of times for good measure) and finally selecting A2DP it still shows Mono? If so, delete it and pair again.

Comment: This is part of a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1574324) and [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/765233/pulseaudio-fails-to-set-card-profile-to-a2dp-sink-how-can-i-see-the-logs-and) work for me when I use the command that starts with `pacmd set-card-profile` after changing the MAC addresses in the command to match my headset.  It is a messy workaround

Comment: Maybe if I buy a Bluetooth Transmitter/Receiver which plugs into the audio jack may help get around this?  Im thinking this because the headphones will connect to the Transmitter/Receiver and then to the jack; so that it will be treated like wired.  (just a thought).

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer just to provide an update as of 2021 on the status of this issue.
That is,

**There is so far, no solution!**

A workaround might be provided by `ofono`, YMMV.

Related:

1. [Bluetooth profile locked to A2DP (high-quality audio sink) but cannot change to HFP/HSP (low-quality bidirectional headset)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985615/bluetooth-profile-locked-to-a2dp-high-quality-audio-sink-but-cannot-change-to)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/1588750/mono-mic-instead-of-stereo-sound-for-bluetooth-headphones-on-ubuntu
3. https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/bluetooth-headset-cant-set-output-as-a2dp-sink-while-using-the-mic-as-input-device/3944