# How do you make Bluetooth device use A2DP profile by default?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 17.10, a2dp

On **17.10**, when I connect a *Bluetooth* device (be it a speaker *JBL Go* or a headphone *MDR-ZX220BT*), it is set to **HSP/HPF** by default.

Moreover, when I try to switch to *A2DP* with the menu from sound settings of the device in gnome control center, nothing happens.

For the switch to a2dp sink to work, I have to use a script I found, called [a2dp.py](https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae/). Which is simply running `pacmd set-card-profile #index a2dp_sink` (and this is not always working)

How to make these devices use **a2dp** by default ?

A second related question, is how to disconnect a Bluetooth device simply without going into gnome control center > Bluetooth > `mydevice` > disconnect. From the top right menu like it was possible in 17.04, for example. I can't find a gnome shell extension for that.

Comment: This is worse with 18.04 as the mentionned script does not help anymore. What I have to do now is disconnect and reconnect the bluetooth device.

Comment: As for your second question, I use `blueman-applet` in panel, but this is in Xfce.

Comment: I am using a gnome-shell extension "Bluetooth Quick Connect". That's handy and that's how I quickly **disconnect-reconnect** to get A2DP now

Comment: Related [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/765233/21005)

Comment: On 19.04, the problem is still there. Now, I am switching off and on the bluetooth device with a gnome shell extension in the menu. I don't think that related answer as any solution. I have not tried all of them, but the solutions do not apply most of the time