# Cannot switch Bluetooth earphones to A2DP on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, a2dp

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 with all latest updates on a Dell XPS 9360 laptop. Earphones are Jabra Elite Active 75t. The earphones pair with the laptop using Bluetooth and work, however sound quality isn't up to scratch (especially compared to using same earphones with an Android phone or Google Chromebook).

I followed these instructions to enable A2DP Bluetooth support on Ubuntu 20.04 using a PPA: https://www.reddit.com/r/Jabra/comments/j5489d/if_you_use_jabra_earbuds_with_linux_you_need_to/

However when I connect the earphones and then open Pulse Audio Volume control they always default to 'HSP'. I then try changing this in Pulse Audio Volume control to A2DP but it doesn't do anything. I see this error in /var/log/syslog:

```
pulseaudio[2046]: Refused to switch profile to a2dp_sink_sbc: Not connected
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer here: [PulseAudio fails to set card profile to 'a2dp_sink'. How can I see the logs and figure out whats wrong?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765233/pulseaudio-fails-to-set-card-profile-to-a2dp-sink-how-can-i-see-the-logs-and)

Basically, add this line:

```
Enable=Source,Sink,Media,Socket
```

under *[General]* in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

Then restart bluetooth (or just restart the computer):

```
systemctl restart bluetooth
```