# Ubuntu 20.04 -- videos won't play in both Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video

Everything works fine at first when I turn on my laptop, but after some time, YouTube videos start to not play. It just keeps loading and reports "please restart your device". Videos will play normally immediately after the restart, however, after a few hours the problem pops up again. I tried to Google but popular suggestions (like clearing up cookies) don't work. Also since both Chrome and Firefox display the same problem, I guess it's probably not browser specific? What's the possible problem here?

Comment: Are there any "shield" or "padlock" icons in the address bar of the browser when you are trying to play videos?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and I found out it is related to the bluetooth headphone I just connect.

Restart bluetooth as describe here solved the problem https://askubuntu.com/a/1030961/271128

Answer (score 2):

I have the same annoying problem, brand new Thinkpad T14. Ubuntu 20.04. Lots of trouble with bluetooth and sound. Instead of rebooting this last time I started settings and saw that Sound output was set to bluetooth speaker. After I changed it to usb audio (usb docking) then youtube etc started working again.
I have tried the 20.04 kernel (5.4) and following latest by ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh - but they just offer different problems, either sound/bluetooth or monitors. Not a full solution but if it saves one from rebooting it helps somewhat.

Comment: I am a bit confused what the solution was: changing the audio output from the system settings? If you want to make your answer clearer, you could split it into two paragraphs, and add this bit first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same problem. It didn't play any video at any website in any browser, including Firefox, Chrome, MS Edge, Vivaldi.
Turn off/disconnect my bluetooth speaker and reconnect and problem was solved.