# Cannot connect to A2DP sink (Ubuntu GNOME 16.04)

Tags: gnome, sound, bluetooth, a2dp

I have tried variuos solutions posted throughout the web. Some worked on Ubuntu 14.04 but not any longer. I have tried the `a2dp.py` script from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763539/bluetooth-speaker-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04) post which yields the following output:

```
Connection MADE
Selecting device:
Device MAC: 00:08:E0:6B:D5:0D
Device ID: bluez_card.00_08_E0_6B_D5_0D
Sink: bluez_sink.00_08_E0_6B_D5_0D
Turning off audio profile.
Disconnecting the device.
Connecting againt.
Setting A2DP profile
Device ID: bluez_card.00_08_E0_6B_D5_0D
Command: pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.00_08_E0_6B_D5_0D a2dp_sink failed with status: 1
stderr: Failure: Input/Output error

Exiting bluetoothctl
```

Trying to connect / disconnect manually has the same result. This bug has been driving me nuts for years. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just try to turning off and on your bluetooth, then connect your hedphones and run the script.