# Can't use bluetooth speaker (Polaris V8) as audio sink. (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

Connection works. But the bluetooth Audio option is not showing in Sound Settings.

[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763539/bluetooth-speaker-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04) didn't help. 
Most other such problems were fixed by changing the audio.conf which doesn't exist in 16.04 anymore.

Besides from that I couldn't find any reasonable solution only more unsolved problems of similar kind.

Comment: Do any of the answers here work? [After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working)

Comment: As there is no audio.conf, i can't really try those solutions. I tried creating my own audio.conf but that didn't help.