# Bluetooth Speaker not doing A2DP Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: bluetooth, 17.04, bluez

Got a Logitech X300, it wont connect via A2DP.  I have done few things in Pulse and /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf to not avail.  Please help.  I just want things to work and get on with my life.

This is one of the post I tried to follow [Bluetooth speaker no sound in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763539/bluetooth-speaker-no-sound-in-ubuntu-16-04)

It has made things worse and I cannot even get my speaker to stay connected for more than a second.

I tried purging all the things, but I do not even know how to reset drivers.  I am a general computer user that wants a solid alternative to windows, but can't get shit like a bluetooth speaker to work.

Comment: Assuming you can undo whatever you've done??, what you needed to do is on this page under "Workaround 2: disable pulseaudio's bluetooth in gdm". Note that that file (`/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/default.pa`) doesn't exist in Ubuntu so you'd need to create it first, then populate as shown. Probably a reboot is also needed.

Comment: Sorry, forgot link... https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp Also I mention in LP bug on, comment 13 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1489651

Comment: Thank you, I messed with the comment on the bug and did what Tom said in his comment.  Then I followed the Debian wiki and then it started working. Thank you.   If you are able reply with your comment so I can mark it as the answer and help your askubuntu cred.

Comment: This helped me to restore the a2dp at ubuntu 18.04 mate: see my comment at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177536/not-possible-to-connect-to-a2dp

Answer (score 7):

I had (I guess...) the exact same problem as [Richard Grant](https://askubuntu.com/users/578618/richard-grant) using a headset Creative WP-350. It used to work fine on Ubuntu 16.04 and then the problem occurs when I switched to Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.
I was able to connect and pair the headset, and use it with "HFP/HSP" audio profile. When trying to switch to "A2DP" profile, it didn't work and indicate "Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink".

As [doug](https://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug) indicated in his comment, the fix is to disable pulseaudio's bluetooth in gdm. Actually I don't understand the reason why pulseaudio's BT is enabled in Gnome Display Manager but there might be a good reason for that... if anyone can clarify this I'd like to understand.

So the fix is pretty easy, based on this [link](https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser/a2dp#Workaround_2:_disable_pulseaudio.27s_bluetooth_in_gdm) provided by [doug](https://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug), here is what I did:

1. Open a terminal window and type (This first point is user-dependant, the main info follow...)

   ```
   gksudo nautilus
   ```
2. then navigate to /var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse
3. Open default.pa if it exists or create it (I had to), as a regular text file.
4. Add the following lines in the file default.pa

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
   #

   # load system wide configuration
   .include /etc/pulse/default.pa

   ### unload driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
   .ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
     unload-module module-bluetooth-policy
   .endif

   .ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
     unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
   .endif
   ```
5. Save the file, close the Terminal window and reboot.

Comment: This did it for me! Bluetooth speakers were working fine under the out-of-the-box Ubuntu 17.04, and then would disconnect/get incorrectly configured once I switched from Unity to Gnome. The above steps let them connect normally again.

Comment: Confirmed fix also.  GDM and bluetooth don't play nice with each other.