# Not possible to connect to A2DP

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp, blueman

I've got headset SONY that I cannot set to A2DP profile. I've read many questions about that but nothing seems to work. It connects fine via BT, I'm using blueman and Pulse Audio Volume Controle. But when I try to change profile from off or HSP/HFP to A2DP blueman says `Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink`. When I do the same in AudioPulse it changes in the UI (option is set) but the setting doesn't change. Running `pacmd list-cards` in terminal shows:

```
index: 4
    name: <bluez_card.CC_98_8B_E1_56_B6>
    driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
    owner module: 28
    properties:
        device.description = "WH-CH700N"
        device.string = "CC:98:8B:E1:56:B6"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_98_8B_E1_56_B6"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "WH-CH700N"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    profiles:
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 20, available: unknown)
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (priority 10, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: yes)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        headset-input: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

Which seems reasonable: if A2DP is not available then I cannot set it up. But I've managed to set it before but after reconnection, it just stopped working and I cannot do that again.

Could you help me to set that up?

PS. I set in my /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

```
AutoEnable=true
Disable=Headset
Enable=Source
```

However I am not sure if that's ok: I need to use my microphone from my headset as well for videoconf, doesn't `disable=headset` disable it?

Comment: The last posting on this topic helped me restore the a2dp on ubuntu 18.04.x mate - just unplug the USB BT dongle and plug it back, and re-pair (reconnect) the BT device - this is the source https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1786808&sid=a693f0c62e645b15580edb77b1549512#p1786808

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS by installing `pavucontrol`, and appending `Disable=Socket` to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. Restart bluetooth with `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`. Make sure that the headset is selected as the output device in pavucontrol. This was all I had to do to get it to work.

Comment: What is `pavuman` ?

Comment: It appears to be called `pavucontrol` now. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pavucontrol.1.html (it's also possible that I mixed up the names first time around)