# A2DP bluetooth doesn't work on 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, 16.04, a2dp

Just moved from 15.04 to 16.04 and now bluetooth doesnt work properly: I can't connect my speakers as A2DP outputs. Apparently everyone is affected according to the forums, but no fix in sight.

Actually I can connect, but it requires multiple connections/disconnections before it works.

Question is: How to fix this issue? Does anybody know how to make A2DP work right after connecting Bluetooth device?

Here's `dmesg` with some mouse stuff in the middle, hope this help:

```
[45149.479720] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[45149.489738] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[45149.489744] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[45153.420328] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[45162.483412] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[45162.483417] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[45162.766559] input: 00:1E:7C:29:FA:EB as /devices/virtual/input/input27
[45165.364814] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[45165.364819] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[45165.364820] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46812.862253] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[46815.957552] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[46816.087438] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c526
[46816.087445] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[46816.087449] usb 1-2: Product: USB Receiver
[46816.087452] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[46816.089890] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0006/input/input28
[46816.145711] hid-generic 0003:046D:C526.0006: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[46816.147462] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0007/input/input29
[46816.201847] hid-generic 0003:046D:C526.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[46839.610453] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[46839.722492] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[46839.938494] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[46840.154478] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[46840.266493] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[46840.482507] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[46840.698537] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[46840.698682] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[46840.902643] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[46841.106603] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[46841.218546] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[46841.218692] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[46841.422640] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[46841.626542] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 13, error -71
[46841.626577] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[46911.990624] input: 00:1E:7C:29:FA:EB as /devices/virtual/input/input30
[46923.868074] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46923.868079] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46923.878036] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46925.697791] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46925.697795] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46927.304203] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46927.304213] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46929.149917] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46929.149923] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46929.149926] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46936.367972] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46936.377649] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46936.377653] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[46936.645904] input: 00:1E:7C:29:FA:EB as /devices/virtual/input/input31
[46938.998385] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46938.998392] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[46938.998394] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[49731.269824] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49731.269830] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49731.269832] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49754.620517] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 513
[49754.620526] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 513
[49754.620529] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 513
[49756.125056] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49756.125061] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49756.135021] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49756.135027] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49770.617041] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 513
[49770.617047] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 513
[49774.882957] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49774.892967] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49774.892973] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49775.420720] input: 0C:A6:94:7E:2B:72 as /devices/virtual/input/input32
[49776.989287] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[49780.797271] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49780.797277] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
[49782.069554] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
[49782.069563] Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
```

EDIT (with lsusb) :

```
gman@thinkpad:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 056a:00ec Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:029d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0254 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lsusb`

Comment: Anyone has any idea when Canonical is going to sort this issue? I'm really pissed off by this regression, I think I'd prefer to install another distro than diving into bluetooth stuff AGAIN! plus acpi is not working correctly. 16.04 is really crap

Comment: Another distro may not help as the errors are coming from the kernel.  A newer upstream kernel may fix the bluetooth but break other things

Comment: Thanks for the leading tip. I tested a few kernels with manjaro and the 4.x series appears to cause trouble, not just with bluetooth actually. So I moved to Mint 17.3 and its 3.19 kernel. Everything runs smoothly again now.

Comment: Fiddling around with same problem, I found workaround. In Sound settings change the affected device settings to HSP/HFP > disconnect Bluetooth device > connect Bluetooth device again and change to A2DP in Sound setting. It temporarily solves same problem for me, it is only workaround, setting is lost after reboot, but at least I can enjoy A2DP.

Comment: AskUbuntu is a question and answer site, not a bugtracker. Please report your findings to Launchpad if you expect a canonical employee to provide a fix for the issue.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I edited this post to make it a question, not a fix request, there must be some clever way to automate the need to manually reconnect until A2DP is enabled.

Comment: @Mike I made some notes when I had this problem which started in versions prior to 16.04 involving pactl to reload the modules, pacmd to set the profiles for the card and bluetoothctl with a here document to poweroff and re-pair, which didn't work so well, here are my notes: http://paste.ubuntu.com/18747929/

Comment: l had the same problem. See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1574324

What I did was to downgrade to bluetooth from wily, that works perfectly!