# 14.04 bluetooth lag (latency, delay) and skipping

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

i came across:

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/405294
2. [Pulseaudio not detecting bluetooth headset automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically)
3. [How to get a consistent bluetooth audio playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519937/how-to-get-a-consistent-bluetooth-audio-playback) (didn't help me)

i can direct audio to my bluetooth device, though i experience lots of skips.

```
$ tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog | grep -i bluetooth
Aug  2 22:29:56 orion pulseaudio[3227]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 209917 us (= 37028 bytes) in audio stream
Aug  2 22:30:01 orion pulseaudio[3227]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 293454 us (= 51764 bytes) in audio stream
Aug  2 22:30:08 orion pulseaudio[3227]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 80787 us (= 14248 bytes) in audio stream
Aug  2 22:30:17 orion pulseaudio[3227]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 258969 us (= 45680 bytes) in audio stream
Aug  2 22:30:17 orion pulseaudio[3227]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 181144 us (= 31952 bytes) in audio stream
Aug  2 22:30:37 orion pulseaudio[3227]: [bluetooth] module-bluetooth-device.c: Skipping 46465 us (= 8196 bytes) in audio stream
```

here is more information about my system:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

$ uname -r
3.19.0-25-generic

$ cat /etc/*release* | grep -i dist
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"

$ lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0

$ ls -l /lib/firmware/brcm | grep hcd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  28266 Jul 28 19:15 BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd

$ modinfo wl | grep parm
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string
```

does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

when i turn on the wifi i experience these errors, whereas with wifi off, no such skipping occur.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; btusb` terminal command.

Comment: Sry, I gave a wrong command. Please add also `lsusb`.

Comment: Did you install firmware?

Comment: @Pilot6: can please clarify to eliminate any confusion?

Comment: OK. Please give output of `ls /lib/firmware/brcm`.

Comment: @Pilot6: now i understood what you meant. updating my post.

Comment: And also output of `modinfo wl | grep parm`

Comment: @Pilot6: done, i've updated my post.

Comment: This is bluetooth and wifi interference. I do not know how to fix it for this module, if it is possible at all.

Comment: @Pilot6: as always, thank you for your help. maybe it is worth to mention again, when i turn off the wifi, everything works without skipping (though there is a delay).

Comment: Maybe someone finds a solution. You are unfortunate with this chip.

Comment: @Pilot6: it is a dell vostro 3460, with "ubuntu ready" sticker :|

Comment: I had the same issue. for me it worked to get out my wifi and Bluetooth module, clean the contacts and put it back in. don't do it when your laptop is on. It's simple and worth a try. edit: The problem was gone for few minutes. Now it doesn't skip but it has 0.5 sec delay